# Project.json AutoMoq cannot resolve Moq 4.1

Tags: asp.net, moq, dnx, autofixture, project.json

I am trying to use `AutoFixture.AutoMoq 3.40.0` with `Moq 4.2.1510.2205` in an ASP.Net 5.0 project but I'm hitting the problem that;

```
The dependency moq >= 4.1.1308.2120 could not be resolved.
```

This is weird because AutoFixture.AutoMoq depends on `moq (>= 4.1.1308.2120)` (see https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq) so it *should* work fine with `Moq 4.2.x` (shouldn't it?)

I have created a new, empty project and just added the two dependencies to reduce the problem to its core.

Project.json looks like this;

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "DependencyTest Console Application",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Moq": "4.2.1510.2205",
    "AutoFixture.AutoMoq": "3.40.0"
  },

  "commands": {
    "DependencyTest": "DependencyTest"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {}
  }
}
```

As soon as I try to build this otherwise empty project I get the above error. If I remove the reference to `Moq` in project.json (or point it to a 4.1.x version) then it compiles. Unfortunately, the codebase I'm trying to put this into already makes use of features from Moq 4.2.

Looking in `project.lock.json` it *looks* like the >= dependency on Moq 4.1 is translated into a fixed dependency on 4.1 which would imply that there is a problem with how the dependencies are worked out by dotnet?

I have tried changing the order that the packages are listed in project.json, tried using `dnu restore` and tried deleting `roaming/nuget/nuget.config`, all to no avail.

Comment: Isn't this the same as this issue? https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/541

Comment: It is, yes. Thank you!

Comment: It's addressed in [AutoFixture.AutoMoq 3.40.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture/3.40.1).

Comment: Thanks Mark, much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the package definition. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324660/nuget-cannot-find-newer-dependency) answer: replace "moq" in "Moq"